# why is this not collapsing in html

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this code where the content supposed to collapse and only one set supposed to be present at a time. I have the correct libraries added, but once embedded in an html page, it doesnt work correctly. I cannot find the issue. It still displays the content at the same time. Code taken from http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/nuNsp/83/

```css
.collapse.in { min-height: 50px;border: 1px solid blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="myGroup">
    <button class="btn dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#keys" data-parent="#myGroup"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Keys </button>
    <button class="btn dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#attrs" data-parent="#myGroup"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Attributes</button>
    <button class="btn dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#edit" data-parent="#myGroup"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Edit Details</button>
    
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="collapse indent" id="keys">
            keys
        </div>
    
        <div class="collapse indent" id="attrs">
            attrs
        </div>
    
        <div class="collapse" id="edit">
            edit
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"I have the correct libraries added"_ - no you don't, the fiddle uses bootstrap v2.0.4 and you put v3.3.7 in your snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are having issues with library versions.

Check below I have changed the bootstrap js and css versions same as in the example you provided.

```css
.collapse.in { min-height: 50px;border: 1px solid blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.0.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="myGroup">
    <button class="btn dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#keys" data-parent="#myGroup"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Keys </button>
    <button class="btn dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#attrs" data-parent="#myGroup"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Attributes</button>
    <button class="btn dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#edit" data-parent="#myGroup"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Edit Details</button>
    
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="collapse indent" id="keys">
            keys
        </div>
    
        <div class="collapse indent" id="attrs">
            attrs
        </div>
    
        <div class="collapse" id="edit">
            edit
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```